# Laptop HP530 has the same brightness with battery than with AC power

Tags: windows, power-supply, power-management, laptop

I have a notebook (HP 530) and I always noticed that with the AC power cable plugged the brightness of the monitor is greater than without it (i guess its to save power when running on battery). But today I notice that there's no change if I plug/unplug the wall power cable, the brightness is always as if the AC power cable is plugged even when it's not.

THe laptop is running Win XP, and on Control Panel > Power options, I dont see anything that could configure this setting.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP remembers last setting used for both battery and AC. Just use Fn+<somekey> to increase/decrease brightness and it should remember this as new setting.

<somekey> for HP 530 are F7 and F8. Just press <Fn>+<F7> to decrease brightness and <Fn>+<F8> to increase it.